# Android Kotlin: Unresolved reference

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout, android-fragments

I'm trying setup an adapter using MainAdapter.kt inside my NewsFragment.kt but I get Unresolved reference. It will be nice if there is a solution to this problem. I'm new to Kotlin and would like your help. Much appreciated.

2 errors:
Unresolved reference: runOnUiThread.
Unresolved reference: homeFeed.

```
runOnUiThread {
worldnews.adapter = MainAdapter(homeFeed)
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RpzBd.png)

NewsFragment.kt

```
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import com.example.inprogress.R
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder
import controller.MainAdapter
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_news.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_news.view.*
import okhttp3.*
import java.io.IOException

class NewsFragment : Fragment() {
    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private var param1: String? = null
    private var param2: String? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        arguments?.let {
            param1 = it.getString(ARG_PARAM1)
            param2 = it.getString(ARG_PARAM2)
        }

        fetchJson()

    }

    fun fetchJson() {

        val url = "https://api.letsbuildthatapp.com/youtube/home_feed"

        val request = Request.Builder().url(url).build()

        val client = OkHttpClient()
        client.newCall(request).enqueue(object: Callback {
            override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) {
                val body = response?.body()?.string()
                println(body)

                val gson = GsonBuilder().create()
                gson.fromJson(body, HomeFeed::class.java)

                runOnUiThread {
                worldnews.adapter = MainAdapter(homeFeed)
                }

                println("Execution success!")
            }
            override fun onFailure(call: Call, e: IOException) {
                println("Execution failed!")
            }
        })

    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_news, container, false)

        view.worldnews.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)

        return view
    }

    companion object {
        /**
         * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
         * this fragment using the provided parameters.
         *
         * @param param1 Parameter 1.
         * @param param2 Parameter 2.
         * @return A new instance of fragment NewsFragment.
         */
        // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
        @JvmStatic
        fun newInstance(param1: String, param2: String) =
            NewsFragment().apply {
                arguments = Bundle().apply {
                    putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1)
                    putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2)
                }
            }
    }
}

class HomeFeed(val videos: List<Video>)

class Video(val id: Int, val name: String, val link: String, val imageUrl: String,
            numberOfViews: Int, val channel: Channel)

class Channel(val name: String, val profileImageUrl: String)
```

MainAdapter.kt

```
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.example.inprogress.R
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.list_row.view.*
import view.HomeFeed

class MainAdapter(val homeFeed: HomeFeed): RecyclerView.Adapter<MainAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {

        return homeFeed.videos.count()
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, position: Int): ViewHolder {
        val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent?.context)
        val cellForRow = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(cellForRow)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val video = homeFeed.videos.get(position)
        holder.view.title.text = video.name
    }

    class ViewHolder(val view: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`runOnUiThread` is an Activity method, but you are in a Fragment. You can use `activity?.runOnUiThread`. The nullsafe call will prevent it from getting called if the fragment has already been detached by the time the callback is called.

`homeFeed` is unresolved because you forgot to create it. Change

```
gson.fromJson(body, HomeFeed::class.java)
```

to

```
val homeFeed = gson.fromJson(body, HomeFeed::class.java)
```

Comment: Wow that was quick. Followed your suggestion and issue resolved now, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You did not create homefeed variable. Try this:

```
            val gson = GsonBuilder().create()
            val homeFeed = gson.fromJson(body, HomeFeed::class.java)

            runOnUiThread {
            worldnews.adapter = MainAdapter(homeFeed)
            }
```

Comment: Thank you Sebastian, much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You have to call activity to use runOnUiThread, because you're inside of a fragment.
Should be like that:

```
activity?.runOnUiThread {
   //Code for the UiThread
}
```

And you have to store the value returned from `gson.fromJson(body, HomeFeed::class.java)` into a val, it is the homeFeed value that's missing.